# CustomScriptExtension on Azure with SQL Server Image not downloading the file because of already used Sequence Number from a Golden Image

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machines

I'm trying to deploy a Windows SQL Server on Azure and running a script on it using the CustomScriptExtension resource.

I've been using CustomScriptExtension successfully when deploying Windows Server SKUs but I can't wrap my head around what is happening (and where can I find more details) when I try to deploy it on a Azure VM running a SQLServer SKU.

e.g. using

```
"imageReference": {
      "publisher": "MicrosoftSQLServer",
      "offer": "SQL2008R2SP3-WS2008R2SP1",
      "sku": "Enterprise",
      "version": "10.60.6001"
},
```

and:

```
{
      "name": "[concat('machineName','/','install-puppet-1')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines','machineName')]"
      ],
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": "[split(concat(parameters('containerUri_1'), parameters('scriptToExecute_1')),' ')]",
          "commandToExecute": "[concat(parameters('commandToExecute_1'),' ',parameters('scriptToExecute_1'), ' -puppetEnvironment ', parameters ('puppetEnvironment_1'), ' -runInterval ', parameters ('puppetRunInterval_1'), ' -vmRegion ', parameters ('vmRegion_1'),  ' -vmEnvironment ', parameters ('vmEnvironment_1'), ' -vmRole ', parameters ('vmRole_1'))]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "storageAccountName": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountName_1')]",
          "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountKey_1')]"
        }
      }
    },
```

Makes the deployment successfull, but the "Downloads" folder in `C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.9.1` is nowhere to be found and the commandToExecute fails with return code != 0

The same code works when applied to this SKUs:

```
"imageReference": {
            "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "offer": "WindowsServer",
            "sku": "2008-R2-SP1",
            "version": "2.127.20180412"
          }
```

UPDATE:
The error seems to be this:

```
[3800+00000001] [06/05/2018 06:29:15.41] [WARN] Current sequence number, 0, is not greater than the sequence number of the most recently executed configuration. Exiting...
```

Which seems to be caused because the SQLServer image has been created using customscript extensions that somewhat "consumed" the sequence number.

Answer (score 1):

From experience i believe you are right a custom script might be on the image already which is why you are getting error from the handler.

It might be by design so your best bet to get accurate answer is to contact support to investigate the image.

I know if you are deploying with PowerShell a `-Forcererun` switch might do the trick but with JSON i am not sure.  You might try the `forceUpdateTag`

Comment: Small update: I contacted support and it seems they released a new version of the SQLServer2008 image where CSE is working again (it may be due to them creating the image using the 1.7 CSE Handler which doesn't get overwritten on the first run).
In fact if you uninstall the CSE from Azure Portal, after deploying the template, and redeploy the same template, the script gets applied successfully

Comment: Great. 

If that the issue, you should make use you have `"autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true` in your JSON to prevent versioning issue.